# Generalizations of Fubini-Tonelli's theoem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory

[Fubini-Tonelli's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Failure_of_Fubini%27s_theorem_for_non-integrable_functions): If $(X, A, \mu)$ and $(Y, B, \nu)$ are $\sigma$-finite measure spaces and $f: X\times Y \to [0,\infty]$ is a measurable function, then
$$ \int _{X}\left(\int _{Y}f(x,y)\,{\text{d}}y\right)\,{\text{d}}x=\int _{Y}\left(\int _{X}f(x,y)\,{\text{d}}x\right)\,{\text{d}}y=\int _{X\times Y}f(x,y)\,{\text{d}}(x,y).$$

- Is it possible to generalize the theorem by replacing the fact that $f$ is non-negative and measurable by some other assumptions weaker than $f \in L^1(X\times Y)$?
- Does this theorem extend in any way to the case where $f$ is a distribution (for example, if I want the dependence on $x$ in $f$ to be given by a Dirac delta)?

Comment: If $f$ isn't $\ge 0$ and isn't in $L^1$, then what do the integral signs mean?

Comment: If $f\geq 0$,   but not $L^1$ the result is also true and  all terms  are $=\infty$. Recall that for a nonnegative  measurable function $$\int_S f(s)\mu[ds]:=\sup_{0\leq g \leq f} \int_S g(s) \mu[ds] $$,  where the sup is taken over all nonnegative elementary functions $\leq f$. The integral of a nonnegative elementary function is defined in an obvious way.  Can you give a concrete example of function $f(x,y)$ whose "*dependence on $x$ is given by a  Dirac delta*" ?

Comment: Concerning the first question, it is sufficient to assume that the integral of $f$ is defined, meaning that either the positive or the negative part of $f$ has finite integral. This is an obvious remark, but it is also the largest possible extension of the result (if the integral is not defined, the question is meaningless, as noted by Jochen Glueck).

Comment: Concerning the second question, you may prove that the value of a distribution $u(x,y)$ tested onto a tensor product of test functions $f(x)\otimes g(y)$ coincides with the value of $u$ first applied to $f$ in $x$, then to $g$ in $y$. This requires some assumtptions on $u$ I think